# tip bottom right to input field should be responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, validation

I am new to CSS.

Trying to align these input field validation tooltip this is fiddle:
[**http://jsfiddle.net/fade3r5f/**](http://jsfiddle.net/fade3r5f/)

can anyone help how can I do this.? I can able to move it to left and right but cant able to do like shown in the below image

```css
body {
  padding: 5em 3em;
}
input {
  padding: .5em;
}

p {
  position: relative;
}
.error {
  position: absolute;
  top: -3.5em;
  left: 0;
  padding: .5em 1em .4em;
  background-color: #f66;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
}
.error::after,
.error::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 15px;
  border: solid transparent;
}
.error::after {
  margin-left: 1px;
  border-top-color: #f66;
  border-width: 7px;
}
.error::before {
  border-top-color: #f00;
  border-width: 8px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <input type="text" size="40" />
  <span class="error">Please enter text</span>
</p>

<p>
  <input type="email" size="40" />
  <span class="error">Please enter email</span>
</p>
```

**I am trying something like this (but it should come bottom to input field):**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to like this:

```css
body {
  padding: 5em 3em;
}
input {
  padding: .5em;
}
p {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom:15px;
  float:left;
  clear:both;
}
.error {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -2.5em;
  right: -68px;
  padding: .5em 1em .4em;
  background-color: #f66;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  width: 120px;
  z-index:10;
}
.error::after,
.error::before { 
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left:-5px;
  border: solid transparent;
}
.error::after {
  margin-left: -4px;
  border-bottom-color: #f66;
  border-width: 7px;
  top: -14px;
}
.error::before {
  border-bottom-color: #f00;
  border-width: 8px;
  top: -16px;
}

@media (max-width:479px) {
  .error {
    right:0;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>
  <input type="text" size="40" />
  <span class="error">Please enter text</span>
</p>

<p>
  <input type="email" size="40" />
  <span class="error">Please enter email</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Comment: You can just set `right:0` in media css... check here http://jsfiddle.net/fade3r5f/2/

Comment: I did that but it is crossing the input field.

Answer (score 2):

```css
body {
  padding: 5em 3em;
}
input {
  padding: .5em;
  margin: .5em;
}
p {
  position: relative;
}
.error {
  position: absolute;
  top: -2.6em;
  left: 11em;
  padding: .5em 1em .4em;
  background-color: #f66;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
}
.error::after,
.error::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 4.5em;
  border: solid transparent;
}
.error::after {
  margin-left: 1px;
  border-top-color: #f66;
  border-width: 7px;
}
.error::before {
  border-top-color: #f00;
  border-width: 8px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <input type="text" size="40" />
  <span class="error">Please enter text</span>
</p>

<p>
  <input type="email" size="40" />
  <span class="error">Please enter email</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this to your CSS:

```
p {
  position: relative;
  width: 320px;
}

input {
  padding: .5em;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.error {
  position: absolute;
  top: -40px;
  right: 0;
  padding: .5em 1em .4em;
  background-color: #f66;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

And if you are using bootstrap then it's quite simple as bootstrap already has tooltip available with different positions.
You just need to overwrite some CSS.